# Java: Pass actual <T extends Event> class. (Generics Problems)

Tags: java, generics

I've made my own `EventExecutor` class, which has the type `<T extends Event>`.

```
public interface EventExecutor<T extends Event> {

    ...
    public abstract void execute(Event event);
}
```

and I know right now that this up here is wrong, because I'm wanting to pass in:

```
public abstract void execute(T event);
```

I've been working on an `Event Management System`, and when an `Event` isn't cancelled after all other events have ran, certain code will run from the `EventExecutor` as shown:

```
// event parameter should be of type T.
EventManager.call(event -> {
    // code here.
}, Class<? extends Event>, Object... eventParameters);
```

The problem here is since the `EventExecutor` method `execute` has the parameter of `Event`, that means `event ->` is of type `Event`, and not the wanted class that `extends Event`, so that means I have to do some casting, which isn't what I want to do.

The problem that keeps me from using the generic type of `T` is my `EventManager` class's method `call`:

```
public static void call(EventExecutor<? extends Event> eventExecutor, Class<? extends Event> eventClass, Object... eventArgs) {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        if (!checkIsEventClassRegistered(eventClass)) return;
        try {
            Event event = null;

            Class<?>[] constructorParameters = EventUtilities.getArrayOfClasses(eventArgs);
            Constructor<?> constructor = eventClass.getDeclaredConstructor(constructorParameters);

            event = (Event) constructor.newInstance(eventArgs);

            // HERE:
            if (!callAllRegisteredMethods(event)) eventExecutor.execute(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'll admit, I'm new to generics, and I don't see what's so wrong with everything. I've tried casting `event` (in the `eventExecutor.execute(...)` method) to `T`, but it tells me to create the method in `EventExecutor` called `eventExecutor.execute(T)`, but then `EventExecutor` throws an error, because it wants `T` to be a class that I create in the same package.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
So basically, in the end I want to be able to not have to cast to my wanted `Event` class:

```
EventManager.call(event -> {
    // Have this automatically be recognized as an instance of MyEventClass?
    System.out.println(event.getText());
}, MyEventClass.class, new String("text"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make `call` a generic method?

```
public static <T extends Event> void call(
   EventExecutor<T> eventExecutor, Class<T> eventClass, Object... eventArgs) {
  synchronized (LOCK) {
    if (!checkIsEventClassRegistered(eventClass)) return;
    try {
      Class<?>[] constructorParameters = EventUtilities.getArrayOfClasses(
          eventArgs);
      Constructor<?> constructor = eventClass.getDeclaredConstructor(
          constructorParameters);

      T event = eventClass.cast(constructor.newInstance(eventArgs));

      if (!callAllRegisteredMethods(event)) eventExecutor.execute(event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Note I replaced the cast to a call to `Class.cast()`.

*Edit:* The only reason why `EventExecutor` has to be generic is because you want to pass in an anonymous function/class to do the execution, and you want that function/class to depend on the actual type of the event. To avoid confusion, I would call it an `EventCallback`, since `EventExecutor` sounds similar to `java.util.concurrent.Executor`, so I was left wondering why you would want more than one.

Incidentally, it's probably not a good idea to call so much code that isn't under your control while you are in a synchronized block.

Comment: my `call` method is from my `EventManager` class which isn't generic.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove `EventManager` can be non-generic and still have generic methods. That's what I showed above. Of course, if the solution in your comment works, then it sounds like `EventExecutor` shouldn't be generic, in which case `call` doesn't need to be, either.

Comment: Also, to answer your question about `EventExecutor` being generic, it's because when the `EventManager.call()` method is called, I'm wanting to return the event for use if the `Event` isn't cancelled.

`EventManager.call(event -> { /* code Here */ }, MyEventClass.class, Object... args);` And I wanted to avoid having to cast that `Event` Object to the wanted `Event` subclass.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove `EventExecutor.execute()` doesn't return anything, so I unless two different subclassed of `Event` need to be handled by two different `EventExecutor` instances, I still don't see why `EventExecutor` should be generic. If you want `EventManager.call()` to return a specific `Event`, then it makes sense to make that one method generic as I did above. If you `EventExecutor.execute()` should return an Event, please update your question and show where the return value is used.

Comment: `T extends Event` is the parameter to `EventExecutor#execute`. It gives me my Event class with the new, modified values, and prevents me from having to cast my Event to a subclass.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove if `EventExecutor` was not generic and took in an `Event`, you wouldn't need to cast to pass it a subclass of `Event` or an object of type `T extends Event`. Note that the Java `Executor` class takes a `Runnable`, not a `T extends Runnable`.

Or are you saying that the `EventExecutor` internally needs to know the difference between passing a `GreenEvent` vs a `PurpleEvent`?

Comment: @CoderMusgrove my bad, you want to pass in an anonymous function that depends on the subtype. So `EventExecutor` should be generic